# Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint distributions $p(x,y) = \theta^{x+y+2}$, $0 \leq x < y < \infty$. Find the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint distributions $p(x,y) = \theta^{x+y+2}$,  $0 \leq x < y < \infty$. Find the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

$$p_X(x) = \sum_{x+1}^\infty p(x,y)$$
$$ = \sum_{x+1}^\infty \theta^{x+y+2}$$
$$ = \theta^{x+2}\sum_{x+1}^\infty \theta^{y}$$
$$ = \frac{\theta^{2x+3}}{1-\theta}$$

This is not the correct answer. I approach $p_Y$ in a similar manner:

$$p_Y(x) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty p(x,y)$$
$$ = \sum_{x=0}^\infty  \theta^{x+y+2}$$
$$ = \theta^{y+2}\sum_{x=0}^\infty  \theta^{x}$$
$$ = \frac{\theta^{y+2}}{1-\theta}$$

This is also incorrect.

Comment: Is there any indication that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables?

Comment: There is not. I am assuming they are discrete because a previous part of the question asks for what values of $\theta$ is this possible. I proceeded under the assumption that they are discrete and got the correct answer.

Comment: @HMPtwo as I can see, your approach for the discrete variables is wrong (as you said, the answer is invalid). Maybe they are continuous?

Comment: @openspace Well, although that is certainly the case, that's not *necessarily* the case, since he also has a few mistakes of algebra.